# Weight training and cardio

Tags: weightlifting

I am training on weights for 3 alternative days in a week on Mon, Wed and Fri for about an hour and on Tuesday and Thursday I am doing cardio on tread mill for an hour. I am not sure if this is ok to train like this. I can really use a expert opinion on this. Hope you will get back to me with an answer soon.

Thanks and regards
Zack

Comment: I hereby give you permission to train like this.

Comment: Yes, sounds good to me.  Mixing up cardio and resistance and recovery at the weekend.  Maybe add some intervals to treadmill or try running outside.  Maybe add more specific question as to what aspect your worried about in question, you may get more useful answers

Answer (score 5):

First, let me say that your program seems reasonable enough. It's pretty common to do cardio on off days, with many people doing a similar program as you. There are some things you might want to consider, though:

**Physical exhaustion:** 
Weight training at a high intensity can exhaust your body to a degree where cardio becomes harmful. This is especially true if you have any weak spots or previous injuries. I myself, for example, can not do heavy squats on monday and do cardio on a bike on tuesday, as my knee is quite weak and won't support that workload.

**Psychological exhaustion:** 
Training every day can be very rewarding, but it can also put you under a lot of stress. This is highly individual and depends on many factors, like how it's going at work, family troubles or just pushin youself too hard.

**Recovery:** 
Make sure your recovery is good enough for you to be able to take 5 days of sports a week. If you're on a diet, you might recover slower and need to adjust. Also sleep enough. Aim for 8 hours or more a day.

**Conclusion:** 
In the end, your training program will have to fit *you*, no expert's opinion will make it work, if for some reason it doesn't fit you. Try it, and if it doesn't work, adust it to your needs.